# How to select a field in addition to everything else?

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Server I had the very convenient ability to make a query like this:

```
SELECT phone_number, last_known_location, * 
  FROM missing_female_pilots 
 WHERE last_name = 'Earhart'
```

How can I do something similar in Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use table alias :

```
SELECT t.phone_number, t.last_known_location, t.* 
FROM missing_female_pilots t WHERE t.last_name = 'Earhart'
```

Or just prepend table name before `*` :

```
SELECT phone_number, last_known_location, missing_female_pilots.* 
FROM missing_female_pilots  WHERE last_name = 'Earhart'
```

Comment: You have just given me a tremendous convenience.  Thank you.  Steve